# Class becomes null when exception is thrown

Tags: c#, xaml, ui-automation

I'm building a desktop application in WPF and I'm debugging an error that is triggered in a property changed method in code behind for a UserControl.

```
    private void ErrorPanel_OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(this.ErrorMessage).RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged);
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint on the line in that method I hover over this and see a UserControl of the correct type. But when I execute that line it throws a object reference null exception, and this is null, suggesting that the UserControl was wiped out.

The definition of the ErrorMessage is as follows

```
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ErrorMessage"
                               Uid="7"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               Text="Error message"
                               ToolTip="Error message"                               
                               AutomationProperties.HelpText="Error message"
                               AutomationProperties.Name="Error message"

                               Focusable="True" 
                               FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
                               FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource MyFocusVisual}" 
                               FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                        />
```

**Edit**

The stack trace is

```
  at FACTAsync.Views.MonitoringPlanListView.ErrorPanel_OnIsVisibleChanged(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\TFS\CAMD Software Tools\FACT\FACTAsync\FACTAsync\Views\MonitoringPlanListView.xaml.cs:line 44
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseDependencyPropertyChanged(EventPrivateKey key, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateIsVisibleCache()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnVisibilityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(Boolean dependencySourcesChanged, Boolean initialValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnDependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourceInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnToggle()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at FACTAsync.Program.Main() in C:\TFS\CAMD Software Tools\FACT\FACTAsync\FACTAsync\Program.cs:line 60
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137221/discussion-on-question-by-kleineg-class-becomes-null-when-exception-is-thrown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.FromElement` returned null, and calling `RaiseAutomationEvent` on that caused the `NullReferenceException`.